# Hello World example in MVC approach to PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Can anyone provide a very simple example of Hello World in MVC approach to PHP?

Comment: MVC is not a pattern to be used for "hello world" examples. It is used when application, that follows OOP principles, becomes too complicated and additional limitations must be imposed to give it a controllable structure.

Comment: Why would you close that type of question???

Comment: There is an extensive answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4925159/201453

Answer (score 34):

Here's some "Hello, World" MVC:

#### Model

```
function get_users() {
    return array(
        'Foo',
        'Bar',
        'Baz',
    );
}
```

#### View

```
function users_template($users) {
    $html = '<ul>';

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $html .= "<li>$user</li>";
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

#### Controller

```
function list_users() {
    $users = get_users();

    echo users_template($users);
}
```

The main idea is to keep separate the *data access* (model) from *data presentation* (view). The controller should be doing no more than wiring the two together.

Comment: hm, why does the view consist of a function with so much php and so few xhtml?

Comment: @Natrium, any constructive comments?

Comment: @tharkun, so much PHP? Is just a for loop and some concatenation. I didn't want to introduce a templating system based on PHP. I wanted a straight, clear example of separation of concerns. Too much markup would have created useless noise in my opinion.

Comment: this article is so nice!
now I know MVC much more!

Comment: nice example, but "a view should never contain any logic except if else or foreach". i can copy that.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the most basic example. Your index.php file is the controller, gets some data from the model, then includes the HTML via a view file.

```
/* index.php?section=articles&id=3 */

// includes functions for getting data from database
include 'model.php';

$section = $_GET['section'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

switch ( $section )
{
    case 'articles':
        $article = getArticle( $id );
        include 'article.view.php';
}
```

.

```
/* article.view.php */

<html>
<head>
<title><?=$article['title']?></title>
</head>

<body>

<h1><?=$article['title']?></h1>
<p><?=$article['intro']?></p>
<?=$article['content']?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

The [QuickStart of Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart) is a not too bad example of "simple application" *(not an "Hello World", but not much more -- and using MVC for an "Hello World" application is a bit like using a nuclear bomb to kill a bug)*, based on Zend Framework, and using MVC.

After, if you want to get a bit farther, you can take a look at the electronic book [Survive The Deep End!](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/) -- still work in progress, but an interesting read anyway.

That's with ZF ; I suppose you can find the same kind of stuff with other MVC Frameworks like Symfony or CakePHP.

Comment: I'm sure he has no customer requirement for a "Hello, World" application.