# how to implement mvc in core php

Tags: php

how is mvc architecture used in php without any framework?

Comment: By intentionally separating your Model, View and Controller code.

Comment: I think you may want to see a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497497/hello-word-example-in-mvc-approach-to-php

Answer (score 14):

**Updated 2020-02-11**: Refactoring the answer to include a few best practices and being closer to PHP 7.4.

## Simplest PHP MVC approach

Thousands words does not compete with a clean example, so here is a simple use case:

Imagine you want to display a page describing a "car" (given a "car id") from an imaginary car vendor: http://example.com/car.php?id=42 (will be http://example.com/car/42 later).

Very basically, you can structure your code with an hierarchy like:

A configuration directory (this isn't part of the MVC architectural pattern):

```
+ config/
  - database.php
        <?php
        return new PDO(getenv("DB_DSN"), getenv("DB_USER"), getenv("DB_PASSWORD"));
```

A folder for your document root (scripts acting like **Controllers**):

```
+ htdocs/
  - car.php
        <?php
        $carService = new CarService(require "config/database.php");
        $car = $carService->getById($_GET["id"]);
        require "car.php";
```

A folder encapsulating your **Model**/business logic (hint: "Thin Controllers, Fat model"):

```
+ src/
  - CarService.php
        <?php
        class CarService {
            private PDO $database;

            public function __construct(PDO $database) {
                $this->database = $database;
            }

            public function getById(int $id): CarEntity {
                return $this->database->query(
                    "SELECT model, year, price " .
                    "FROM car " .
                    "WHERE id = $id"
                )->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, CarEntity::class);
            }
        }
```

A last folder containing all your **Views**(/templates):

```
+ views/
  - car.php
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Car - <?= htmlspecialchars($car->model) ?></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1><?= htmlspecialchars($car->model) ?></h1>
        Year: <?= htmlspecialchars($car->year) ?>
        Price: <?= htmlspecialchars($car->price) ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

For the code above to work, you will need PHP to be configured with:

```
include_path="/the/path/to/src:/the/path/to/views"
```

## To go further

### Nice URLs

You might want nice URLs, if using Apache you can achieve this with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/car/(\d+)$ /car.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This enables writing URLs like http://example.com/car/42 which will be internally converted to http://example.com/car.php?id=42

### Views as classes

In the above solution, `car.php` is included from the *global scope*, that is why `$car` is directly available, but `$carService` too!

One way to restrict what the templates may access is to transform it as a class:

`views/CarView.php`:

```
<?php
class CarView {
    private CarEntity $car;

    public function __construct(CarEntity $car) {
        $this->car = $car;
    }

    public function __invoke(): void {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Car - <?= htmlspecialchars($this->car->model) ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?= htmlspecialchars($this->car->model) ?></h1>
        Year: <?= htmlspecialchars($this->car->year) ?>
        Price: <?= htmlspecialchars($this->car->price) ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
}
```

and then adapting the controller:

`htdocs/car.php`:

```
<?php
$carService = new CarService(require "config/database.php");
$view = new CarView($carService->getById($_GET["id"]));
$view();
```

### Reusing views

Using plain PHP files as templates, nothing prevents you from creating headers.php, footers.php, menu.php,... which you can reuse with [`include()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)/[`require()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) to avoid duplicated HTML.

Using classes, re-usability can be obtained by combining them, for example, a `LayoutView` can be responsible for the global layout, and, in turn, calls another `View` component:

```
<?php

class LayoutView {
    protected string $lang;

    public function __construct(string $lang) {
        $this->lang = $lang;
    }

    // __invoke(): for embracing the "Single Responsibility" principle
    public function __invoke(View $view): void {
        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= $this->lang ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><?= htmlentities($view->getTitle()) ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php ($view)(); ?>
</body>
</html>
        <?php
    }
}
```

and CarView could be implemented like:

`views/CarView.php`:

```
<?php
class CarView implements View {
    private CarEntity $car;

    public function __construct(CarEntity $car) {
        $this->car = $car;
    }

    public function getTitle(): string {
        return $this->car->model;
    }

    // __invoke(): for embracing the "Single Responsibility" principle
    public function __invoke(): void {
?>

<h1><?= htmlspecialchars($this->car->model) ?></h1>
Year: <?= htmlspecialchars($this->car->year) ?>
Price: <?= htmlspecialchars($this->car->price) ?>
<?php
    }
}
```

In turns, the controller would use it like this:

`htdocs/car.php`:

```
<?php
$carService = new CarService(require "config/database.php");

(new LayoutView("en"))(
    new CarView($carService->getById($_GET["id"]))
);
```

## Conclusion

This is far from being production-ready code, as other aspects aren't addressed by those examples: *dependency injection*/*inversion of control (IoC)*, input filtering, class autoloading, namespaces,... The goal of this answer is to focus as much as possible on the main aspect of MVC.

This is very much in the same spirit as Rasmus Lerdorf mentioned on: https://toys.lerdorf.com/the-no-framework-php-mvc-framework.

One should not forget that MVC remains a **pattern**. Software Patterns are reusable principles to solve common problems, if they would be reusable **code**, they would have been named "libraries" instead.

Frameworks like Zend Framework, Symfony, Laravel, CakePHP and the likes proposes a structure to adopt an MVC approach but can't enforce it, MVC, as a special case of *Separation of concerns* needs to be **learned** and **understood** to be achieved.

Comment: Wow ! Can someone please give this guy a medal or something ? Seriously, excellent post ! I'm wondering why ALWAYS the younger, new ones and - yes i'm really saying that - good looking guys make much much better answers than the nerds. Dude, repect !

Answer (score 11):

I think generally using one of the common frameworks is probably the way to go. The reason is that many good developers have spent a long time writing, bug-fixing, tweaking and polishing to create something solid for basing your site on. The best thing to do is to find one you like, learn it and stick with it (unless you find a reason not to). When I work with PHP, my choice is generally [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), but there are also [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/), [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) and a [bunch of others](http://www.phpwact.org/php/mvc_frameworks).

If you still want to use the MVC pattern without an existing framework, you either have the choice of putting your own together or just logically separating each concern out from each other - this is the core tenet of MVC, the frameworks just help you achieve it.

Rasmus Lerdorf [wrote about his minimal approach to the MVC pattern in PHP](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html) in 2006. Might be worth a read. You may also be interested in a mini-framework such as [F3::PHP](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/) (PHP 5.3+ only) - looks pretty promising.

Comment: You suggest that PHP isn't a Web Framework and that MVC is bound/facilitated by using one. MVC is achieved when you understand it's just a specific case of "Separation of concerns". Frameworks won't prevent you to have business logic implemented in controllers/views.

In most other general purpose languages: you have nothing native to parse HTTP requests, manipulating headers, cookies, sessions, buffering the output,...

PHP has all of the above in its core.

The evil is to re-invent the (square) wheel, which is prevented by re-using *libraries* rather than *frameworks*.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the [PHP MVC Tutorial](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/) to find out how to use simple MVC pattern from scratch, not in an existing framework.

Answer (score 1):

It's not.  Core PHP is a "start in global namespace statement and expression oriented language".  You need extra code (and an optional URL Rewriter) to implement any kind of MVC architecture.  That extra code is your framework.

Comment: I disagree. MVC is an abstract concept. You don't need to use object oriented programming style to realise it.

Answer (score 1):

[This is how you can use MVC in php without any framework](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a MVC pattern you just have to separate your data persistence code ("model", mostly database stuff), the main application logic ("controller") and your presentation to the outside world ("view", like HTML pages or RSS feeds).

IF you just don't mix these three parts in your code, you already have a really basic MVC architecture. Just build distinct classes for your model, view, and controller layers, come up with a well structured way how they talk to each other and then stick to it!

For the sake of code maintainability you should ALWAYS try to work that way.

Comment: The model is **not** just or mostly the database! The model is your actual application. It contains everything that doesn't fall into the responsibility of controller and view. This can be domain objects, service layers, persistence layers, *everything*.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can fill entire books, even bookstores about the model layer. But for keeping things simple, I think it's sufficient to say "It's mostly your database abstraction" since 90% of all model implementations actually handle databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try integrating Pear DB Layer, Smarty, PHP GACL in your core code to achieve an MVC architecture.

Comment: 1. Pear DB only deals with relational databases, your data may come from non-relational databases or even from web services, it does not address the "Model".
2. Smarty is a template engine, not required to have the principle of "Views".
3. PHP GACL is about access lists, this has nothing to do with the foundation of the MVC pattern. (Not that it can't play with)

Answer (score 0):

By writing your own MVC framework that fallows MVC pattern and OOP principles :)

1. You need to have Front Controller so every HTTP Request goes through one file, index.php, app.php or what ever you want. This way you can configure application in one place.
2. From there you need Routing mechanism that will analyze HTTP Request, current URL, HTTP Header verb / method, and based on that you will invoke appropriate Controller Method / Action Controller.
3. From Controller, you can access your Models that will deal with "heavy lifting", deal with database and domain / business logic etc. And from Controller you can render Views.

So you need at least Front Controller, Router / Dispatcher, Controller, Models and Views to have simple MVC arhitecture.

You would do that joust as other MVC web frameworks do, with slight variations depending on your preferences.

Take a look at some simple frameworks like Codeigniter, and read their source code to get idea how they are doing MVC.

And have fun building your MVC! Its all about the fun after all :D