# How to make a controller in this sample model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

How to make a controller in this model and pass to view? Sorry I'm just new in using mvc oop. I just want to learn the basic. Kinda confused on controller, since I know the model will hold the queries on the database. I dont know how to pass or work on controller.

Am I doing it right way in Model and Controller? I just need some advice. On how to handle Model and Controller correctly.

And I'm not using any framework just php itself and mvc pattern.

Model

```
class userModel{

    public function __construct(){  
        $dbCon = new DbConnector();
        $this->dbCon = $dbCon->getConnection();
    }

    public function select(){
        $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM users;";
        $results = $this->dbCon->query($myQuery);
        return $results;
    }
}
```

controller

```
 require_once("../model/userModel.php");

    class userController{
    private $userModelSelector;

    public function __construct(){
       $this->userModelSelector = new userModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: every framework has subtle differences. which one are you using or is this something custom?

Comment: @mistermartin its just custom just doing it using pure php coding

Comment: that makes this question very broad. do you have any other components of your custom framework built or is this it? you might start by reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951707/how-to-implement-mvc-in-core-php), or [here](https://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html).

Comment: @mistermartin post edited. I don't know if im doing right in controller part. But I know It's just called the model

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten I take it you're using the same connection method from your other question? Are you getting errors from this, either via php and/or the query?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes im using same connection on my other question. I just implement now the MVC pattern. But basically I don't know how to use Controller. Just on my example. I query users on my database on my model. So how the controller works on the model?

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten Ok. I take it that you want to use the custom `select()` function dynamically and if so ,how? TBH and as I stated in your other question earlier, that I'm not the best at OOP. If you explained your question better, then maybe others will also be able to help and offer a solution and to edit your question with what the ultimate goal is.

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten if not, then all you'd need to do is add `while($getUsers = $results->fetch_array()){
          echo $getUsers['username'] . "<br>";
      }` to the `select()` method and then do `$user = new userModel();
return $user->select();` if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry I did'nt get where to put .. U can provide some edit codes as answer? hehe

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten I posted something for you below in the answers area.

Answer (score 0):

you can rename this calss to `User_model` and create new class `User` in class `User` you can call class `User_model` 
by this way you can call model from controller

Comment: See edited post. I don't know if i've done it right in the controller. @Abanoub Makram

Comment: Is that the right way to to do it in controller? Like I have no idea coz I'm just started to learn MVC concept. @Abanoub Makram

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the `while` loop (from your previous question's code) to your `select()` method:

```
class userModel{

    public function __construct(){  
        $dbCon = new DbConnector();
        $this->dbCon = $dbCon->getConnection();
    }

    public function select(){
        $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM users;";
        $results = $this->dbCon->query($myQuery);

// I added this bit
      while($getUsers = $results->fetch_array()){
          echo $getUsers['username'] . "<br>";
      }
        return $results;
    }

}
```

and then use that method passed from your controller in the return:

```
$user = new userModel();
return $user->select();
```

it will work, given if this is what the question is about.

Comment: how about the view ?

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten that's why I asked you in comments, as to what exactly you wanted to do. Can you explain more about "the view"?