# What is the right way to make a PHP website object oriented and MVC?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I was wondering what is the right way to use PHP in an Object oriented way and with a goo MVC architectural pattern?

I tried for a project at school to use MVC and make it Object oriented, but I am sure I wend the wrong way, because when it came to deploying the website I had so many issues it was not usable. Obviously now I am trying to figure out how, if I started all over would I go around doing it?

Would it make such a big difference using a framework like Zend? If anyone could point me to a good structured open source example I would be very happy, because I just can't figure out the "proper" way to do it.

**Edit**
My main problem is not understanding MVC or OO separately, but using them together with PHP.

Comment: please go through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+do+MVC+php and point out which parts are still unclear to you, so we do not have to reiterate what is already there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hello Word example in MVC approach to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497497/hello-word-example-in-mvc-approach-to-php)

Comment: By the way, its a pity that PHP does not have a standard file structure, so EVERY php coder will ask himself over and over again: "how do i structure my code". Java has a standard file structure. The same things are always at the same place. Nice idea !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll suggest the following:

1. Understand the underpinnings of an MVC by skimming thru
   [The no-framework PHP MVC framework](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html) (don't mind the code).
2. Test MVC with a big name framework like [Symfony](http://docs.symfony-reloaded.org/quick_tour/index.html) to see "best practices" at play. Their documentation and code is worth spending time on.
3. Experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some already created and tested framework. (They really spare time and code-writing)
[This is a good website](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) for different PHP frameworks comparison.

In my opinion, if you want something small and light, you can check [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/)